# Firebase: observing childAdded returns existing / old records?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a query (written in swift):

```
    FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "\(ORDERS_PATH)/\(lId)")
      .child("orders")
      .observe(.childAdded, with: { firebaseSnapshot in

      let orderObject = firebaseSnapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

      let order = AppState.Order(
        title: orderObject["name"] as! String,
        subtitle: orderObject["item_variation_name"] as! String,
        createdAt: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(orderObject["created_at"] as! Int / 1000)),
        name: "name",
        status: AppState.Order.Status.Pending
      )

      f(order)
    })
```

My database looks like this:

[image]

I want it to just listen all NEW incoming orders. However, every time it initially loads it fetched a bunch of existing orders with it, which isn't what I want.

I do have a `created_at` (an int that represents that time e.g. 1478637444000) on each of the orders, so if there's a solution that can utilize that that works too.

Is there something wrong with my query?

Comment: That's the expected behaviour. However, you can take advantage of the `child_added` events for existing data firing before the `value` event. If you listen for a single `value` event, any `child_added` events that arrive after the `value` will be for new data.

Comment: Wait so which event do I use if I don't want to load anything initially and only want new records added after i start observing?

Comment: It'll always do the initial load. The best you can do is ignore it. If you have a large amount of data, the approach won't work.  I don't know of another solution, as the `child_added` events always fire for existing data. The approach I mentioned is the way Google have done it in AngularFire2.

Comment: Oooo really?? If I just want new records, Should I just ignore the first time the block is run then?

Comment: The code in the block would need to check a variable that's set when a `value` event is received in another listener (that listens for a *single* event only). You'd ignore all `child_added` events until you've received the single, initial `value` event for the same ref. I'd type up an answer, but my swift is very rusty.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Observers always fire once and read in "all the data".

A .value observer reads in everything in the node at once, where as a .childAdded observer (from the docs)

> This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again
>   every time a new child is added to the specified path.

If you think about your question, what you are actually looking for is a sub-set of all of your data. This is achieved via a query.

Your query will be to observe all .childAdded events that occur after a certain timestamp. So that's what you need to do!

Craft an observe query leveraging queryStartingAtValue(the timestamp to start at) which will return all children added after that timestamp.

Comment: @LanceSamaria This is a pretty old question and the code would be different depending on your use case. I would suggesting asking a specific question for your use case, include what you've tried and a snippet of your Firebase structure and we'll take a look!

Comment: thanks, I asked this question a couple of hours ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62410591/4833705. I started working on some new code on my end and literally just added it as an update. The new code seems long winded but I couldn't see any other way together around the issue

Answer (score -2):

Swift3 Solution:

Just write multiple observers.

You can retrieve your previous data through the following code:

```
queryRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in


    //Your code

})
```

> observeSingleEvent of type .value just calls once and retrieves all previous data

and then observe the new data through the following code.

```
queryRef?.queryLimited(toLast: 1).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

 //Your Code

        })
```

> queryLimited(toLast: 1) with bserving of type .childAdded is being called every time that a new data is available